# Liferay Concurrent FileEntry Upload

Tags: java, file, concurrency, upload, liferay

**Problem Statement :**

In liferay i have to import a zip file in to some folder in liferay cms, So far I had implemented serial unzipping of the zip file create it's folder and then it's files. The problem here is that the whole process takes a lot of time. So I had to use parallel approach in creating folders and creating files.

**My Solution :**

I have used a java **java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService** to create a **Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREDS)** where NTHREDS is the number of threads to be run in parallel (say 5)

1. I read all the folder paths from the zip and placed , list of zip
   entires (files) against folder path as a key in HashMap
2. Traversed all keys in the map and created folders serially
3. Now traversed the list of zip entries (files) from map and passed to a     thread worker,one file for each worker, these workers are then sent to
   ExecutorService to Execute

So far i didn't find any significant reduction in time of the whole process, am i moving in the correct direction? Does liferay support concurrent file addition? What am I doing wrong?

I will be much thankful for any help in this regard

below is my code

```
imports 
...
...
public class TestImportZip {

    private static final int NTHREDS = 5;
    ExecutorService executor = null;
    ...
        ...
        ....
    Map<String,Folder> folders = new HashMap<String,Folder>();
    File zipsFile = null;

    public TestImportZip(............,File zipFile, .){

        .
                .
        this.zipsFile = zipFile;
        this.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREDS);
    }

       // From here the process starts
    public void importZip() {

        Map<String,List<ZipEntry>> foldersMap = new HashMap<String, List<ZipEntry>>();

        try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipsFile)) {
            zipFile.stream().forEach(entry -> {

                   String entryName = entry.getName();
                   if(entryName.contains("/")) {

                       String key = entryName.substring(0, entryName.lastIndexOf("/"));

                       List<ZipEntry> zipEntries = foldersMap.get(key);

                       if(zipEntries == null){
                           zipEntries = new ArrayList<>();
                       }

                       zipEntries.add(entry);

                       foldersMap.put(key,zipEntries);

                   }
               });

            createFolders(foldersMap.keySet());

            createFiles(foldersMap);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createFolders(Set<String> folderPathSets) {

        // create folder and put the folder in map
       .
       .
       .

    folders.put(folderPath,folder); 
    }

    private void createFiles(Map<String, List<ZipEntry>> foldersMap) {
          .
              .
              . 
         //Traverse all the files from all the list in map and send them to worker
       createFileWorker(folderPath,zipEntry);

    }

    private void createFileWorker(String folderPath,ZipEntry zipEntry) {

        CreateEntriesWorker cfw = new CreateEntriesWorker(folderPath, zipEntry);
        executor.execute(cfw);
    }

    class CreateEntriesWorker implements  Runnable{

        Folder folder = null;
        ZipEntry entryToCreate = null;


        public CreateEntriesWorker(String folderPath, ZipEntry zipEntry){

            this.entryToCreate = zipEntry;
            // get folder from already created folder map
            this.folder = folders.get(folderPath);

        }

        public void run() {

            if(this.folder != null) {
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipsFile)) {

                        InputStream inputStream = zipFile.getInputStream(entryToCreate);

                        try{

                            String name = entryToCreate.getName();
                            // created file entry here 
                        }catch(Exception e){

                        }finally{

                            if(inputStream != null)
                                inputStream.close();
                        }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823

Comment: @OlafKock, understood and post deleted from other site..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simplified code does not contain any Liferay reference that I recognize. The description you provide gives a hint that you're trying to optimize some code, but don't get any better performance out of your try. This typically is a sign that you're trying to optimize the wrong aspect of the problem (or it's already quite optimized).

You'll need to determine the actual bottleneck of your operation in order to know if it's feasible to optimize. There's a common saying that "premature optimization is the root of all evil". What does it mean?

I'll completely make up numbers here - don't quote me on them: They're freely invented for illustration purposes. Let's say, that your operation of adding the contents of a Zip file to Liferay's repository is distributed to the following percentages of operational resources:

- 4% zip file decoding/decompressing
- 6% file I/O for zip operations and temporary files
- 10% database operation for storing the files
- 60% for extracting text-only from word, pdf, excel and other files stored within the zip file in order to index the document in the full-text index
- 20% overhead of the full-text indexing library for putting together the index.

Suppose you're optimizing the zip file decoding/decompressing - what overall improvement of numbers can you expect?

While my numbers are made up: If your optimizations do not have any result, I'd recommend to reverse them, measure where you need to optimize and go after that place (or accept it and upgrade your hardware if that place is out of reach).

Run those numbers for CPU, I/O, memory and other potential bottlenecks. Identify your actual bottleneck #1, fix it, measure again. You'll see that bottleneck #2 has gotten a promotion. Rinse repeat until you're happy